# New plumbing - Lose Water Pressure in Outdoor Hose

Tags: plumbing, hose, shutoff

First time soldering plumbing.  Replaced shut-off and new frost free bib.  The water pressure in house is normal.  When I use the hose it spurts out water normally with good pressure then 2 seconds later there is pressure loss where it just pours out.

I checked the frost bib and stem is okay.  Checked the plumbing connections with paper towel around and no leaks but i noticed that there was dripping water from the top of the shut-off where the nut is.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Do i need to replace the shut off again because it is faulty?

At the plumbing when hose is activated i notice good pressure to start then it sort of sucks back and then little to no pressure?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 seconds of good flow followed by low flow there is a restriction upstream.  The longer the burst the further up stream the restriction is.

The leak at the ball valve stem, You may have melted the oring or nylon seat that seals the shaft when soldering. The heat deforming the seal causing the leak.

I have had luck removing the nut and handle then the nut on the shaft. Orings are easy and cheap the ones that have nylon sleeves can be a bit tougher to find.

In some cases I have purchased another valve same size and brand and pulled the seal out to repair but most have been orings.

Comment: Indeed you were spot on Ed thank you!  Although I checked for hose leaks and replaced the ends there was still something wrong.  Tested again with a 3ft hose and separate nozzle and no pressure loss.  Thanks! Now I just need to solve the valve drip issue as you noted.